# Does an element animation run after setting display to a visible state?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does an animation run after setting the display to block?

I'm setting the animation style of an element and then setting the display from none to block. It is playing the animation for me but I've read that display doesn't trigger animations. Who is correct?

Part of the Code:

```
// method 1 - enable a media query
var animation = "fadein 1s ease-out";
element.style.setProperty("animation", null, "important");
element.style.setProperty("animation", animation, "important");
enableQuery(rule); // manually enable a media query


// method 2 - set display none to block
element.style.display = "block";
var animation = "fadein 1s ease-out";
element.style.setProperty("animation", null, "important");
element.style.setProperty("animation", animation, "important");
```

CSS

```
@keyframes fadein {

    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

}
```

If you display is none outside of a media query and then you enable a media query that sets the display to block then that would cause the animation to play? Does requestAnimationFrame fit into any of this?

Comment: Maybe show your code that makes you doubt what you read? Also a reference to what you have read would be useful.

Comment: Display block and none do not animate between themselves.

Comment: Would enabling the media query be what's playing the animation? Also, I switch between none and block too and then I use the code above to start it.

Comment: Display and opacity are two different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#animations):

> Setting the display property to none will terminate any running animation applied to the element and its descendants. If an element has a display of none, updating display to a value other than none will start all animations applied to the element by the animation-name property, as well as all animations applied to descendants with display other than none.

I have nothing more to add. I guess it's pretty clear.

Comment: If you display is none and then you enable a media query to display block then that would be causing the animation to play? Does requestAnimationFrame fit into any of this?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts for the first part, yes. Changing the display with media query will trigger the animation. For the requestAnimationFrame, I don't know